# 8 bit unsigned number addition and subtraction overflow

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, unsigned

I have trouble understanding when overflow occurs in unsinged addition and subtraction.
For example,

```
   1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
+  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
  __________________
   0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Because of the 1 in the MSB, it results as overflow.
I understand this problem, but when it gets to subtraction, I have trouble determining when it is overflow

For example,

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1               
-  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

---

(After applying 2's complement)

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
+  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

---

```
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Therefore the result should be "no overflow" because there is no 1 carry out in the end. However, the answer says "overflow". Could you please tell me why?

Comment: I think this questions should be asked on - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably call this *underflow* not *overflow*.

Think about it like this. You are trying to compute *x* − *y*. Using two's complement you are implementing this as *x* + (2<sup>*N*</sup> − *y*) = 2<sup>*N*</sup> + (*x* − *y*). So the result will only correctly represent (*x* − *y*) if there is an overflow carry bit 2<sup>*N*</sup> that fell off the left. Otherwise the result you get is the two-s complement representation of a negative subtraction result.